# FindExecutable for Windows 8 Metro Apps

Tags: c#, file-extension, file-association

I have been trying to use the FindExecutable function below.

```
[DllImport("shell32.dll")]
static extern int FindExecutable(string lpFile, string lpDirectory, [Out] StringBuilder lpResult);
```

But it doesn't seem to return any value in lpResult if the lpFile is associated with a Metro App (Reader for PDF for example) while it returns a value greater than 32 (meaning it was successful)

Are there any tricks to get this function to work with Metro Apps?  Or are there any alternatives?  (Looked at GetThumbnailAsync in StorageFile but its documentation specifies Windows Store apps only so it is unavailable to me)